# NSolve for system of polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I would like to find all the solutions to the following system of 8 polynomial equations for the variables `w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8`

```
eqs = {1/162 (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (-27 w1^3 - 27 w1^2 w3 + 54 w1 w2 w3 + 
    18 w1 w3^2 + w3^3 - 216 w1^2 w4 + 216 w1 w2 w4 - 
    72 w1 w3 w4 - 108 w1^2 w5 + 54 w1 w2 w5 - 72 w1 w3 w5 + 
    36 w2 w3 w5 - 3 w3^2 w5 - 144 w1 w4 w5 + 72 w2 w4 w5 - 
    24 w3 w4 w5 - 27 w1 w5^2 - 9 w3 w5^2 - 24 w4 w5^2 - 2 w5^3) - 1/2 w1 Log[2] == 0,

   -(1/54) (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (27 w1^2 w2 - 18 w2^3 + 18 w1^2 w3 + 
    18 w1 w2 w3 - 36 w2^2 w3 + 12 w1 w3^2 - 9 w2 w3^2 + 2 w3^3 + 
    72 w1 w2 w4 - 72 w2^2 w4 + 24 w2 w3 w4 - 18 w1^2 w5 + 
    54 w1 w2 w5 - 18 w2^2 w5 + 18 w2 w3 w5 + 2 w3^2 w5 + 
    24 w2 w4 w5 - 12 w1 w5^2 + 15 w2 w5^2 - 2 w3 w5^2 - 2 w5^3) - 1/2 w2 Log[2] == 0,

    1/54 (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (27 w1^2 w2 - 9 w1^2 w3 + 18 w1 w2 w3 + 
    18 w2^2 w3 - 9 w1 w3^2 + 33 w2 w3^2 + 5 w3^3 - 72 w1^2 w4 + 
    72 w1 w2 w4 - 144 w1 w3 w4 + 120 w2 w3 w4 - 40 w3^2 w4 - 
    63 w1^2 w5 + 36 w1 w2 w5 + 18 w2^2 w5 - 96 w1 w3 w5 + 
    48 w2 w3 w5 - 26 w3^2 w5 - 24 w2 w4 w5 - 32 w3 w4 w5 - 
    6 w1 w5^2 - 9 w2 w5^2 - 15 w3 w5^2 + 8 w4 w5^2 + w5^3 - 
    27 w1^2 w6 - 54 w1 w2 w6 + 54 w2^2 w6 - 54 w1 w3 w6 + 
    18 w2 w3 w6 - 15 w3^2 w6 + 72 w1 w4 w6 - 72 w2 w4 w6 + 
    24 w3 w4 w6 + 54 w1 w5 w6 - 54 w2 w5 w6 + 6 w3 w5 w6 + 
    24 w4 w5 w6 + 9 w5^2 w6 + 72 w1^2 w7 - 144 w1 w2 w7 + 
    72 w2^2 w7 + 48 w1 w3 w7 - 48 w2 w3 w7 + 8 w3^2 w7 + 
    48 w1 w5 w7 - 48 w2 w5 w7 + 16 w3 w5 w7 + 8 w5^2 w7) - 1/2 w3 Log[2] == 0,

    1/108 (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (9 w1^2 w3 + 3 w1 w3^2 + w3^3 - 
    18 w1^2 w4 + 18 w2^2 w4 + 12 w1 w3 w4 + 24 w2 w3 w4 + 
    18 w3^2 w4 - 144 w1 w4^2 + 120 w2 w4^2 - 56 w3 w4^2 + 
    27 w1^2 w5 + 18 w1 w3 w5 + 6 w2 w3 w5 + 6 w3^2 w5 - 
    60 w1 w4 w5 + 36 w2 w4 w5 - 28 w3 w4 w5 - 32 w4^2 w5 - 
    6 w1 w5^2 + 6 w2 w5^2 - 3 w3 w5^2 - 14 w4 w5^2 - w5^3 + 
    6 w3^2 w6 - 24 w3 w4 w6 + 24 w4^2 w6 - 18 w1^2 w7 - 
    36 w1 w2 w7 + 36 w2^2 w7 - 60 w1 w3 w7 + 36 w2 w3 w7 - 
    18 w3^2 w7 + 96 w1 w4 w7 - 96 w2 w4 w7 + 32 w3 w4 w7 + 
    36 w1 w5 w7 - 36 w2 w5 w7 - 4 w3 w5 w7 + 32 w4 w5 w7 + 
    6 w5^2 w7 + 216 w1^2 w8 - 432 w1 w2 w8 + 216 w2^2 w8 + 
    144 w1 w3 w8 - 144 w2 w3 w8 + 24 w3^2 w8 + 144 w1 w5 w8 - 
    144 w2 w5 w8 + 48 w3 w5 w8 + 24 w5^2 w8) - 1/2 w4 Log[2] == 0,

    1/54 (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (9 w1^2 w3 + 12 w1 w3^2 + 3 w2 w3^2 + 
    3 w3^3 + 72 w1^2 w4 + 72 w1 w3 w4 + 16 w3^2 w4 + 9 w1^2 w5 + 
    9 w1 w2 w5 + 33 w1 w3 w5 + 12 w2 w3 w5 + 16 w3^2 w5 - 
    84 w1 w4 w5 + 48 w2 w4 w5 - 32 w3 w4 w5 - 36 w1 w5^2 + 
    15 w2 w5^2 - 16 w3 w5^2 - 12 w4 w5^2 - 5 w5^3 - 27 w1^2 w6 + 
    54 w1 w2 w6 + 18 w1 w3 w6 + 18 w2 w3 w6 + 9 w3^2 w6 - 
    72 w1 w4 w6 - 24 w3 w4 w6 - 81 w1 w5 w6 + 27 w2 w5 w6 - 
    33 w3 w5 w6 + 12 w4 w5 w6 - 54 w1 w6^2 + 27 w2 w6^2 - 
    18 w3 w6^2 - 144 w1^2 w7 + 108 w1 w2 w7 - 120 w1 w3 w7 + 
    48 w2 w3 w7 - 24 w3^2 w7 + 12 w1 w5 w7 - 24 w2 w5 w7 + 
    4 w3 w5 w7 + 4 w5^2 w7 + 72 w1 w6 w7 - 36 w2 w6 w7 + 
    24 w3 w6 w7) - 1/2 w5 Log[2] == 0,

   -(1/162) (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (-9 w1 w3^2 - 9 w2 w3^2 - 8 w3^3 - 
    72 w1 w3 w4 - 48 w3^2 w4 - 27 w1 w2 w5 - 9 w1 w3 w5 - 
    18 w2 w3 w5 - 18 w3^2 w5 + 36 w1 w4 w5 + 48 w3 w4 w5 + 
    54 w1 w5^2 - 27 w2 w5^2 + 39 w3 w5^2 - 12 w4 w5^2 - 2 w5^3 + 
    108 w1 w3 w6 - 108 w2 w3 w6 + 18 w3^2 w6 + 432 w1 w4 w6 - 
    216 w2 w4 w6 + 288 w3 w4 w6 + 243 w1 w5 w6 - 81 w2 w5 w6 + 
    207 w3 w5 w6 - 36 w4 w5 w6 - 27 w5^2 w6 + 81 w2 w6^2 + 
    54 w3 w6^2 - 216 w4 w6^2 - 162 w5 w6^2 - 54 w6^3 + 
    216 w1^2 w7 - 108 w1 w2 w7 + 360 w1 w3 w7 - 144 w2 w3 w7 + 
    120 w3^2 w7 - 108 w1 w5 w7 + 72 w2 w5 w7 - 36 w3 w5 w7 - 
    12 w5^2 w7 - 648 w1 w6 w7 + 324 w2 w6 w7 - 360 w3 w6 w7 + 
    216 w6^2 w7) - 1/2 w6 Log[2] == 0, 

    1/108 (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (w3^3 + 12 w1 w3 w4 + 12 w2 w3 w4 + 
    8 w3^2 w4 + 96 w1 w4^2 + 64 w3 w4^2 + 15 w1 w3 w5 + 
    9 w3^2 w5 + 84 w1 w4 w5 + 12 w2 w4 w5 + 68 w3 w4 w5 - 
    32 w4^2 w5 + 30 w1 w5^2 + 6 w2 w5^2 + 29 w3 w5^2 - 
    40 w4 w5^2 - 14 w5^3 + 27 w1^2 w6 + 54 w1 w3 w6 + 
    15 w3^2 w6 + 36 w1 w4 w6 + 36 w2 w4 w6 + 36 w3 w4 w6 - 
    96 w4^2 w6 + 63 w1 w5 w6 + 18 w2 w5 w6 + 63 w3 w5 w6 - 
    144 w4 w5 w6 - 60 w5^2 w6 + 27 w1 w6^2 + 45 w3 w6^2 - 
    72 w4 w6^2 - 81 w5 w6^2 - 54 w6^3 + 90 w1^2 w7 + 
    36 w1 w2 w7 + 144 w1 w3 w7 + 36 w2 w3 w7 + 58 w3^2 w7 - 
    480 w1 w4 w7 + 192 w2 w4 w7 - 256 w3 w4 w7 - 336 w1 w5 w7 + 
    120 w2 w5 w7 - 196 w3 w5 w7 + 32 w4 w5 w7 + 14 w5^2 w7 - 
    396 w1 w6 w7 + 72 w2 w6 w7 - 252 w3 w6 w7 + 288 w4 w6 w7 + 
    204 w5 w6 w7 + 180 w6^2 w7 + 336 w1 w7^2 - 168 w2 w7^2 + 
    168 w3 w7^2 - 168 w6 w7^2 - 648 w1^2 w8 + 432 w1 w2 w8 - 
    720 w1 w3 w8 + 288 w2 w3 w8 - 192 w3^2 w8 + 144 w1 w5 w8 - 
    144 w2 w5 w8 + 48 w3 w5 w8 + 24 w5^2 w8 + 864 w1 w6 w8 - 
    432 w2 w6 w8 + 432 w3 w6 w8 - 216 w6^2 w8) - 1/2 w7 Log[2] == 0,

    1/324 (-1 + 2^(1/3))^3 (3 w3^2 w4 + 9 w2 w4^2 + 3 w3 w4^2 + 
    52 w4^3 + 12 w3 w4 w5 + 48 w4^2 w5 + 6 w3 w5^2 + 30 w4 w5^2 + 
    8 w5^3 + 54 w1 w4 w6 + 18 w3 w4 w6 - 9 w4^2 w6 + 
    27 w1 w5 w6 + 9 w3 w5 w6 + 18 w4 w5 w6 + 27 w5^2 w6 + 
    27 w4 w6^2 + 54 w5 w6^2 + 27 w6^3 + 36 w1 w3 w7 + 
    12 w3^2 w7 + 180 w1 w4 w7 + 36 w2 w4 w7 + 132 w3 w4 w7 - 
    204 w4^2 w7 + 144 w1 w5 w7 + 18 w2 w5 w7 + 108 w3 w5 w7 - 
    228 w4 w5 w7 - 108 w5^2 w7 + 108 w1 w6 w7 + 108 w3 w6 w7 - 
    216 w4 w6 w7 - 252 w5 w6 w7 - 216 w6^2 w7 - 468 w1 w7^2 + 
    108 w2 w7^2 - 276 w3 w7^2 + 264 w4 w7^2 + 180 w5 w7^2 + 
    360 w6 w7^2 - 112 w7^3 + 324 w1^2 w8 + 432 w1 w3 w8 + 
    144 w3^2 w8 - 1296 w1 w4 w8 + 648 w2 w4 w8 - 648 w3 w4 w8 - 
    648 w1 w5 w8 + 216 w2 w5 w8 - 360 w3 w5 w8 + 36 w5^2 w8 - 
    648 w1 w6 w8 - 432 w3 w6 w8 + 648 w4 w6 w8 + 432 w5 w6 w8 + 
    324 w6^2 w8 + 1728 w1 w7 w8 - 864 w2 w7 w8 + 864 w3 w7 w8 - 
    864 w6 w7 w8) - 1/2 w8 Log[2] == 0}
```

I tried

```
NSolve[ eqs, {w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8}, Reals]
```

because I am interested only in real solutions for `w1, ..., w8` but it takes a very long time without producing an output. 
Do you have any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Comment: How about use FindRoot？It can give some solutions,but maybe miss some solutions.

Comment: The thing is that I need to find all the solutions

Answer (score 1):

`NSolve` will most probably not lead to a solution.
Here are some hints to nevertheless find numerical solutions:

Use `vars = list` of left hand sides of the equations eqs.

You easily notice that `vars2 = vars.vars == 0` for `w1 == 0, w2 ==0, ..., w8 == 0` (the trivial solution).

Play around with `Random[]` to find non-trivial numerical solutions thus

```
a = 5; 
r := a*(-1 + 2*Random[])
FindRoot[vars, {w1, r}, {w2, r}, {w3, r}, {w4, r}, {w5, r}, {w6, r}, {w7, r}, {w8, r}]

(* {w1 -> 1.0866647931342157, w2 -> -6.495637628594321, 
    w3 -> 0.4002754924331578, w4 -> 0.33218420848258684, 
    w5 -> -6.433160564214913, w6 -> 7.158518588749012, 
    w7 -> -0.8792094540870672, w8 -> 0.32592467680231985} *)
```

For small a you will find the trivial solution, for a at about 4 to 5 non-trivial solutions appear.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Why not RandomReal[{-5,5}]?

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks you for bringing my text into the correct format. How can I avoid bothering you and do it correctky myself?

Comment: You're welcome. To learn to do it yourself see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and specifically on the part that talks about editing posts.

Comment: With FindRoot I will miss some solutions, and I need all the solutions. I can find all the solution by making the hypothesis that 4 ws are zero: repl = {w5 -> 0, w6 -> 0, w7 -> 0, w8 -> 0}; NSolve[eqs /. repl, {w1, w2, w3, w4}] . Is there a way to improve on this and setting to zero 3,2,1 equations iteratively?